# Queue.Peek throws InvalidOperationException if Queue is Empty

Tags: c#

I've got a simple Queue to manage items being added to my application.

From Microsoft's current documentation of their [Queue.Peek Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue.peek(v=vs.100).aspx):

[image: screenshot]

### What is the point of using Peek() to look at the Queue if it still throws an Invalid Operation Exception?

I thought the whole point of Peek() was to have code that did NOT generate exceptions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Even [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collectioull.ns.queue.peek(v=vs.110).aspx) mentions the reason:

> null can be added to the Queue as a value. To distinguish between a
>   null value and the end of the Queue, check the Count property or catch
>   the InvalidOperationException, which is thrown when the Queue is
>   empty.

So the reason for a queue to throw an exception if you try to peek at the first item is that it could be `null`. How do you want to distinguish between a valid `null` value and no item?

The same is true if the queue contains value types like `int`. Should it return -1 if there is no item to peek at? No, -1 could be a valid value so you don't know if there is another item in the queue.

Instead use the `Count` property to check whether or not the queue is empty:

```
var queue = new Queue<int>();
queue.Enqueue(-1);
while (queue.Count > 0)
{
    int current = queue.Peek();         // still in the queue
    Console.WriteLine(queue.Dequeue()); // now empty
}
```

I assume that you're confusing `queue.Peek` with a method like `dataReader.Read`. The difference is that [`Read`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read(v=vs.110).aspx) advances the reader to the next record and just returns a `bool` which indicates whether or not there was a record at all. [`Queue.Peek`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue.peek(v=vs.110).aspx) also returns that "record". It's a different purpose, so don't use `Peek` if you want to know if there is one.

By the way, this behaviour is consistent in the framework. Other methods like  [`Enumerable.First`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb291976(v=vs.100).aspx) also throw an  `InvalidOperationException` if you use them on an empty sequence.

Comment: It just seems like everything else that uses `Peek()` is able to return -1 or null when there is nothing else there. What is the point of `Peek()` then? Just call `Dequeue` and catch the exception there.

Comment: @jp2code: why should `Peek` return `-1` at all? It is supposed to return the first item in the queue. A `Queue<T>` can store anything not only value types like `int`. Also, even if it contains ints `-1` could be a valid number, so you don't know whether this is the first/last or not. The same applies to `null`. Throwing an exception is a hint for you that there is something wrong in the logic. You are asking for another item but there is none. Use `while(myQueue.Count > 0){ // here you can peek }`.

Answer (score 4):

The point of `Peek` is to look at the next element of the queue, without removing it. The fact that it is not removed is the main difference between `Peek` and `Pop` (`Dequeue` in .NET). (That's nothing to do with .NET; for any language's queue structure which has a `Pop` (/`Dequeue`) which returns the popped value, that's the difference between the two.

If the queue is empty, there is nothing reasonable that `Queue` can return. An exception is the only alternative to returning a value, so that's the appropriate behavior. Either catch and handle the exception, or (if you're not worried about race conditions) check whether the queue is empty before calling `Peek`/`Dequeue`.

Comment: I still don't understand why Peek() is even there. The purpose of Peek() is to see if there is anything left in the queue without consuming it, but if nothing is there an exception is thrown. How would somebody write code that uses Peek() without also coding in an exception handler? I mean, why not just Try/Catch a Pop or Dequeue? I am missing the reason for this, apparently. I wish someone could enlighten me.

Comment: @jp2code If you used `Dequeue()` then it would change the queue, which is not what you want. `Peek()` returns the next element *without* changing the queue.

Comment: @jp2code As to how to make sure it won't throw an exception, just don't call it if `Count` is zero. But depending on programming style, you might prefer catching the exception rather than explicitly checking the count.

Comment: jp2code, your statement "The purpose of Peek() is to see if there is anything left in the queue without consuming it" isn't exactly correct. It's quite possible that you would want to examine the properties of the next object in the queue to, for example, see if you want to process immediately or wait for some time, or take some other action prior to processing it.